# Downloading all files in a directory using jQuery or JS, or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, audio

Now, I know that when I post here on SO, it is best if I include code that I've tried. The issue is, I cannot find anything on Google that is specific to my needs. So I am taking a small risk asking this question with no code to show what I've tried, because in reality I haven't been able to try anything except changing file extensions of compressed folders to match the devices used to download them on. So, here it goes -)

I have a folder, it contains 15 .MP3 files. The viewers of the site can download them via an audio player I found online (Royal Audio Player). I want to incorporate a way (not into the Audio Player, in separate HTML using images) that allows my users to have the option of downloading all the MP3 files at once, and not on-by-one.

Is there a way to do this? Any help is appreciated and I apologize again for not providing any code for people to see. Thanks in advance. =)

EDIT: Changed the title to ask about PHP methods also. =)

Comment: I do not think this is possible on client side. Which server side technology are you using ?

Comment: I am running on Apache w/ no Db's or anything, and for the web coding I am using HTML5, and JS/jQuery. I've been told that it is possible to download all the files from a directory using JS upon initiatiion of a user prompt to take place alerting the user they are download a list of files and not just one, once they approve the download commences. But I cannot find out how anywhere on the internet. Maybe I can do it in PHP?

Comment: If you decide to do it on PHP, then this is what you can do. Just provide a download all button to user and when user clicks on it, you get a all on server side and then use php code to make a zip file for all the 15 audio  files and then return the zip file as a response.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a little bit of code. I am not familiar with PHP at all. And all I would need is a starting point of some sort, I can do the rest. Heck, it might not event ake that much coding to do lol. Also, I already have the download all button (not an HTML button but an Image using a href="location", if that helps) in place and don't know where to go from there. Srry, and thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an anchor element like this

```
<a href="/myProject/downloadAll.zip"> Download All </a>
```

And in php, add a route on this path and create a zip and return the zip as a response.

You can use [these examples on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php) to know how to create a zip in php.

Comment: Which one of those options do you think would best fit my needs? As I said I do not know PHP at all lol. It is is quite literally a whole different language to me so I apologize for being such a noob lol. Maybe you can provide a PHP code example? Thanks if you can, and if you cannot I appreciate the help =) Also, I would just link to the ZIP itself but then it will not work for download all MP3's on mobile devices (I assume, since not all mobile devices download and extract ZIP files autmoatically).

Comment: @user3267537 This is the time you read and understand which of the 4 examples fit your needs. Documentation is quite clear there.

Comment: I thank you for your assistance. I did ask for a starting point and you'v definitely provided that. Marked as answer =)

Comment: I am glad you decide to end up solving the problem yourself after some hints. This is the good time you should explore things, do some experiments and make some conclusion so that you never need to say noob to yourself again ;) Cheers!!

Comment: And I thank you again. I guess now that I've successfully learned JS and jQuery I can finally move to PHP. A terrifying idea, I have always been afraid of PHP for some reason and idk why lol. But if I can write fluent JS, I think I'll be fine. And yep, doing it myself after some hints is the only way I'll  learn. Not having others do it for me =)... Thanks again and cheers to you too! =D